# How I can keep alive the process while one of its threads is killed using pthread in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have write a program with 3 threads using pthread in c++, and I want to keep alive the process while the thread 1 is killed. here is my program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a = 0;

void *func (void *arg)
{
   int c = a++;
   cout << "start thread " << c << endl;
   if (c == 1) //I wrote this to thread1 crashes and be killed.
   {
     int d = 0;
     d = 10 / d;
   }
   cout << "end thread " << c << endl;
}

int main ()
{
   pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;
   pthread_create (&tid1, 0, func, 0);
   sleep (1);
   pthread_create (&tid2, 0, func, 0);
   sleep (1);
   pthread_create (&tid3, 0, func, 0);
   sleep (10);
   return 0;
}
```

when I run it with "g++ a.cpp -lpthread", the output is like this:

```
start thread 0
end thread 0
start thread 1
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

that means when thread1 is killed, whole the process will be killed.  Is there any way to keep alive the process while one of its threads is killed? I need that because I want to use other threads of the process, however anyone of the threads be killed.
note that I don't want to use exception handling to avoid killing the thread.

Comment: I think you are in a wrong way. use ++c instead of c++ first. And please clarify your question.

Comment: @SamMokari thank you for your attention. why I must use ++c?!! I need a way to kill a thread without the process be killed. because I want to use other threads of the process, however anyone of them be killed.

Comment: ++c would be about as helpful meeting your goal as compiling with ++g.

Comment: Anyway,  no. Different kind of exception. You can use a signal handler on the FPE signal, but you won't get the result you want. You aren't trying to use this to end a thread, are you?

Comment: @user4581301 no, I want to use other threads of the process, however anyone of its threads be killed. so I want a way to process won't be killed while any of its threads are killed.

Comment: Since you are using pthreads you are probably targeting Linux. On Linux the thread that was running when the signal is raised handles the signal, but I'm not sure if `pthread_self` is safe to call in a signal handler let alone `pthread_kill`. `pthread_cancel` is kinder and less likely to leave the program in a bad state than `pthread_kill`, but isn't that useful unless your thread has a decent cancellation point. If you're going to check "should I cancel?" every iteration, you might as well save yourself a lot of trouble, test if you're about to divide by zero and politely return on true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by ignoring the FPE signal. Here is my new program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
using namespace std;

int a = 0;

void sig_func(int sig)
{
  //some code we want execute when signal recieves, or nothing.
}

void *func (void *arg)
{
  int c = a++;
  cout << "start thread " << c << endl;
  if (c == 1)
  {
    int d = 0;
    d = 10 / d;
  }
  cout << "end thread " << c << endl;
}

int main ()
{
  pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;
  signal(SIGFPE,sig_func);
  pthread_create (&tid1, 0, func, 0);
  sleep (1);
  pthread_create (&tid2, 0, func, 0);
  sleep (1);
  pthread_create (&tid3, 0, func, 0);
  sleep (10);
  return 0;
}
```

and its output is like this:

```
start thread 0
end thread 0
start thread 1
start thread 2
end thread 2
```

that means when thread1 is killed, whole the process won't be killed and next threads could run their functions.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use synchronization mechanisms such as semaphores (using sem_wait(), sem_post()) which is shared among multiple threads to induce delay.

Alternate way is to use while(1) and sleep() inside func(), but consumes CPU cycles when awake.